# How can i save the data into SQL database using websockets? ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, websocket

How can i save the data into SQL database using websockets in ASP.net MVC?
I want to display data on my view. Then, when the data changes - I want to send a new data to the controller and overwrite them on database. And obviously I want to display current data on view. 
This should works as an application for monitoring exchange rates.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         function WebSocketTest()
         {
            if ("WebSocket" in window)
            {
               alert("WebSocket is supported by your Browser!");

               // Let us open a web socket
               var ws = new WebSocket("ws://someurl.com/data");

               ws.onopen = function ()
               {
                  // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
                  ws.send("Message to send");
                  alert("Message is sent...");
               };

               ws.onmessage = function (evt)
               {
                 //  var received_msg = evt.data;
                   var data = JSON.parse(evt.data);
                  alert("Message is received - so now data on view should refresh and save to database...");
               };

               ws.onclose = function()
               {
                  // websocket is closed.
                  alert("Connection is closed...");
               };
            }

            else
            {
               // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
               alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
            }
         }
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="sse">
        <a href="javascript:WebSocketTest()">Run WebSocket</a>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: consider using SignalR

Comment: Yea, i read about that, however still i've no idea what should I do?

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr

Comment: I've seen this before, but there is nothing about external URL (websocket). Only its own hub.

Comment: I don't understand why would you want to limit yourself to WS only. SignalR uses WS too *if it is able to* it just goes beyond this by providing fallback mechanisms for when WS is not available. I don't get what is your problem with having alternatives out-of-the-box. Especially as WS is highly limited in that only the most modern platforms support it.

Comment: Well because this WS isn't my. I've got only link, and i need to pull data (exchange rates) from there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101598/discussion-between-piter-and-balazs).

Comment: Oh so the WS backend is not yours? I was mislead by your `ws://localhost/` line of code. Why don't you just make an ajax call then from within your `ws.onmessage()` sending the appropriate data?